# deprecated repaint() method on mac

Tags: java, applet

I try to make a standard form for simple games, but every time I try to compile it on my mac, it says:

```
move.java:31: error: unreachable statement
        repaint();
        ^

Note: move.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error
```

When I tried to compile it on a windows computer, it worked just fine! I can't find anything about fixing this, and according to the java website the repaint() method isn't deprecated! This is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class move extends java.applet.Applet implements Runnable {

    Image osI;
    Graphics osG;
    Thread runner;
    char currkey;
    int x;
    int y;

    public void init() {
        x = 0;
        y = 1;
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        osI = createImage(size().width, size().height);
        osG = osI.getGraphics();
    }

    public void start() {
        if (runner == null) {
            runner = new Thread(this);
            runner.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            y = 1;
        }
        repaint();
        try { Thread.sleep(1000); }
        catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (runner != null) {
            runner.stop();
            runner = null;
        }
    }

    public boolean keyDown(Event evt, int key) {
        switch (key) {
            case Event.DOWN:
                x = 1;
                break;
        }
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        if (x == 1) {
            g.drawString("x is 1!!!", 150, 150);
        } else {
            g.drawString("x is geen 1!!!", 150, 150);
        }
        if (y == 1) {
            g.drawString("y is 1!!!", 150, 175);
        } else {
            g.drawString("y is geen 1!!!", 150, 175);
        }
        g.drawImage(osI, 0, 0, this);
        osG.setColor(getBackground());
        osG.fillRect(0, 0, size().width, size().height);
        osG.setColor(getForeground());
    }
}
```

Comment: The deprecation and the unreachable code are unrelated. BTW, you might want to do what it suggests: `Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.` if it bothers you.

Comment: That's not saying `repaint` is deprecated, it's saying that your call to `repaint();` is unreachable, and also that *something* is deprecated (and to use the `-Xlint:deprecated` command-line option if you want to see details)

Answer (score 1):

You error isnt saying repaint() is deprecated. In fact, using deprecated methods inst an error at all.

Its because of your infinite loop:

```
while (true) {
    y = 1;
}
repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

This `while-loop`...

```
 while (true) {
     y = 1;
 }
 repaint();
```

Will never exit, therefore, `repaint` can NEVER be called

[`Thread#stop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) is deprecated...

```
runner.stop();
```

You should never use it.  Instead, create a `AtomicBoolean` flag which you can use in your `while-loop` and while it's value is `true`, keep looping.  In your `stop` method, set the `AtomicBoolean`'s value to `false` and the loop will exit.

See [Java Thread Primitive Deprecation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for reasons why `stop` (and other `Thread` methods are deprecated)

[`Applet#size`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#size()) is deprecated...

```
osG.fillRect(0, 0, size().width, size().height);
```

Use `getWidth` and `getHeight`

`java.awt.Applet` is 15+ years out of date.  Seriously, instead, you should be, at the very least, using `JApplet`, but even then, I would recommend moving your core logic to a `JPanel` and simply adding that to what ever container you want to use, apart from gaining double buffering support without any extra work, you also gain the flexibility to decide how to use the component, as frankly, there are better approaches then using an applet now days.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have unreachable code

```
    while (true) {
        y = 1;
    }
```

means that the repaint() method will never be called as the loop never ends.